# Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly freezes

Tags: graphics, freeze, 20.04, segmentation-fault

Once or twice a day Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly freezes.

- No network (can't ssh into it anymore)
- graphics remain frozen
- no usb (so no keyboard, no mouse)
- no bluetooth (no mouse)

Audio repeats 0,5 seconds for about 20 times then it's silent

NO indication in syslog whatsoever

One indication in `kern.log` a few seconds prior to freezing

```
SGI_video_sync[4331]: segfault at e6 ip 0000562097460b8d sp 00007f640a7fa6c0 error 6 in skypeforlinux[5620940cc000+5425000]
```

At other times it was Discord or VNC or any other video-related application.

Tried to switch from NVidea driver to Nouveau - can't get it to work on 4K screen. Renmains 640x480.

Hardware:

- Intel i7 8700
- GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2
- 32 G RAM

Xsensors reports temperatures in the low 30s (centigrade), so that should not be an issue.

Any ideas or additional information required?

Thanks for any useful thoughts

PS: I tried to submit a bugreport, but since I do not know where to look in the first place it seems moot.

@heynnema

thanks for the assist.......

free -h
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       8,8Gi        15Gi       894Mi       7,0Gi        21Gi
Swap:         975Mi          0B       975Mi

vm.swappiness = 60

sudo lshw -C memory

*-firmware

```
   description: BIOS

   vendor: American Megatrends Inc.

   physical id: 0

   version: 0402

   date: 03/19/2018

   size: 64KiB

   capacity: 16MiB

   capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
```

*-memory

```
   description: System Memory

   physical id: 3b

   slot: System board or motherboard

   size: 32GiB

 *-bank:0

      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)

      product: CMK32GX4M2A2666C16

      vendor: Corsair

      physical id: 0

      serial: 00000000

      slot: ChannelA-DIMM1

      size: 16GiB

      width: 64 bits

      clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)

 *-bank:1

      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)

      product: CMK32GX4M2A2666C16

      vendor: Corsair

      physical id: 1

      serial: 00000000

      slot: ChannelB-DIMM1

      size: 16GiB

      width: 64 bits

      clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
```

*-cache:0

```
   description: L1 cache

   physical id: 44

   slot: L1 Cache

   size: 384KiB

   capacity: 384KiB

   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified

   configuration: level=1
```

*-cache:1

```
   description: L2 cache

   physical id: 45

   slot: L2 Cache

   size: 1536KiB

   capacity: 1536KiB

   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified

   configuration: level=2
```

*-cache:2

```
   description: L3 cache

   physical id: 46

   slot: L3 Cache

   size: 12MiB

   capacity: 12MiB

   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified

   configuration: level=3
```

*-memory UNCLAIMED

```
   description: RAM memory

   product: Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM

   vendor: Intel Corporation

   physical id: 14.2

   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2

   version: 10

   width: 64 bits

   clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)

   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list

   configuration: latency=0

   resources: memory:a3416000-a3417fff memory:a341b000-a341bfff
```

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
0402

The machine is a self-built tower with components selected to be good with Linux

Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 12

The NVIDIA driver is 440 stable tested.

There is no swap partition.

The system is not overclocked  and ventilators run with a conservative setting.

Comment: Despite you have 32GB or RAM, do you have a swap partition ?

Comment: What version Nvidia driver? Have you run memtest? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model of your computer. Is your CPU or RAM overclocked? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema   I also see same error in dmesg on asus laptop `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version Q524UQK.304`

Comment: @ScottStensland Please start a new question for your situation.

Comment: I need the exact model # of your motherboard so that I can check if there's a newer BIOS. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them. Like I missed your updates in your question.

Comment: @heynnema I found a newer firmware for the mainboard, will install after work and see what happens.

Comment: Good. Keep me posted. What version BIOS did you find?

Comment: @heynnema: I upgraded from 2404 to 2601. So far no crahses, but it's early days yet. (The thermal management seems to be much better though....)

Comment: Oh, and the board is an ASUS Prime H310-Plus

Comment: Please keep me posted.

Comment: @heynnema Well, it froze again. Nothing in syslog. Nothing in kern.log. Everything green right up to the second it died. I had it running with Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.10 with nary a problem, so I am considering going back to 19.10. I am backed up perfectly, so this would not be too much of a bother.

Comment: I'm not ready to downgrade just yet :-) Did you run memtest? Boot with nomodeset (screen resolution may be off). This will tell us if there's a Nvidia problem. Post syslog at paste.ubuntu.com, and tell me the time it crashed/froze. There's nothing in /var/crash, correct?

Comment: Done. It wouldn't take the full syslog so there is 7 minutes prior to the freeze and the beginning of boot.

Time of freeze: 19:46:54

Nothing in /var/crash

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. Started after I ran VirtualBox. It was running fine for a couple of hours before that.

Comment: @heynnema Memtest starts at 0 passes 13% and remains there, it does not run. Oorking now with the "nomodset" option set. Screen resolution is fine, performance remains to be seen.

Comment: @ubuntububuntu Please start a new question for your problem. Provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: We may have a memory problem. Remove one 16G RAM stick and retry memtest. If it runs 4/4 passes, remove the remaining 16G RAM stick, and re-insert the previously pulled RAM stick into its ORIGINAL slot, and rerun memtest. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Haven't had a chance yet. But since I removed one of the USB-Hubs the machine hasn't crashed. BIOS also doesn't report "no keyboard found" when starting up anymore (the thing that gave me the idea in first place). That's more than 24 hours without crash by now. I will continue to check.

Comment: @slap882 Good find! Was it a powered hub? Thanks for the update!

Comment: @heynnema Yes, it was an old powered USB-2 hub where keyboard, printer and scanner where connected. 48 hrs without crash.

Comment: @slap882 Remember that memtest hung at 13%, so there may be a memory problem lurking. See my previous comment about how to test memory.

Comment: @heynnema Will do the tests, naturally. But when I used a different distribution boot-stick, memtest seemed to start just fine. With the Ubuntu boot-stick it came up with 13% immediately and didn't change after that. Due to time constraints I just let the pop-OS bootstick memtest run for just 1/2 hour, but at least it ran ;-) And thanks a lot for caring :-)

Comment: @heynemma: Well after doing the memtests (2 nights, all is well) and three days of no crash it started again yesterday. To boot I upgraded my laptop to 20.04 with fatal results (black screen after login, erratic behavior in terminal). I guess 20.04 and I are no friends so far :-)
I backed up fully and went to Mint on both machines, which is still sitting on the beaver. 
Both are running smoothly so far and I do like the dark Cinammon theme. So I guess we can close this one......